# Simple SQLAlchemy update table based on value in another table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am a newcomer to SQLAlchemy, so please forgive what must be an elementary question.

I have a database table `properties` (mapped in SQLALchemy as the object `Property`) which contains a field `MEBID`. I have another table `mebs` (mapped in SQLAlchemy as `MEB`). I want to set the properties.MEBID field to mebs.id where properties.PostCode == mebs.PostCode.

I can do this simply in SQL using the command

```
update properties, mebs set properties.mebid = mebs.id where mebs.PostCode = properties.PostCode
```

but am struggling with doing it in SQLAlchemy. If I try the command

```
session.query(Property, MEB).\
  filter(Property.PostCode == MEB.PostCode).\
  update({Property.MEBID : MEB.id})
```

I get

```
InvalidRequestError: This operation requires only one Table or entity be specified as the target.
```

I know that this must be elementary as it's such a fundamental operation, but can't work out how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update:

```
for prop, meb in session.query(Property, MEB).filter(Property.PostCode == MEB.PostCode).all():
    prop.MEBID=meb.id 
    session.add(prop)
```